# what are G_BEGIN_DECLS and G_END_DECLS for?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glib

I've been analyzing the code for some gtk applications and saw that in the .h files there are the G_BEGIN_DECLS and G_END_DECLS macros. The documentation says

> Used (along with G_END_DECLS) to bracket header files

But I didn't understand what I meant.

Comment: That’s not entirely true. The full documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#G-BEGIN-DECLS:CAPS) says: “Used (along with G_END_DECLS) to bracket header files. If the compiler in use is a C++ compiler, adds extern "C" around the header.”. The important part is the second sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These defines should be used in the public headers of C libraries. They aren't really useful for the library itself but they may be useful to C++ applications that want to use the library as they expand to a `extern "C"` block which makes sure that C++ compilers are able to handle the C headers